# Can a MultiButton's bottom underline be disabled?

Tags: codenameone

Can a MultiButton's bottom underline be disabled? I tried `mb.getUnselectedStyle().setUnderline(false);` and `mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());` but not working

I am grouping MultiButtons inside a rounded container and the last button's underline looks kind of ugly. I used MultiButtons instead of Buttons because they need to turn into checkbox buttons when they're pressed for a long time. Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is ComponentGroup the right thing for your use case? https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/ComponentGroup.html

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed. Are you aware of whether it is possible to style ComponentGroup's corner radii via Themes (not css)

Comment: It's a long time that I use CSS only (or Java code) to style, I suggest you to write a new question on Stack Overflow about your request.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to style each individual MultiButton depending on its position in the list (top, bottom, center, or single) programmatically (styling the theme produced strange resizes of the buttons when pressed)

I wish there was a better way for doing this. In the meantime I will paste my code here in case anyone has the same issue

Style for single multibutton (top and bottom rounded)

    `public void setMultiButtonStyleRound(MultiButton mb)
    {
        RoundRectBorder newBorder = RoundRectBorder.create().cornerRadius(4);
        newBorder.stroke(1, false);
        newBorder.strokeColor(0xd6d6d6);
        newBorder.strokeOpacity(255);
        newBorder.shadowSpread(10);
        newBorder.shadowX(0.5f);
        newBorder.shadowY(0.5f);
        newBorder.shadowBlur(10);
        RoundRectBorder newBorder2 = RoundRectBorder.create().cornerRadius(4); //need a border object for each style otherwise it breaks
        newBorder2.stroke(1, false);
        newBorder2.strokeColor(0xd6d6d6);
        newBorder2.strokeOpacity(255);
        newBorder2.shadowSpread(10);
        newBorder2.shadowX(0.5f);
        newBorder2.shadowY(0.5f);
        newBorder2.shadowBlur(10);
        RoundRectBorder newBorder3 = RoundRectBorder.create().cornerRadius(4); //need a border object for each style otherwise it breaks
        newBorder3.stroke(1, false);
        newBorder3.strokeColor(0xd6d6d6);
        newBorder3.strokeOpacity(255);
        newBorder3.shadowSpread(10);
        newBorder3.shadowX(0.5f);
        newBorder3.shadowY(0.5f);
        newBorder3.shadowBlur(10);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xfcfcfc);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(newBorder);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBorder(newBorder2);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBgColor(0xfcfcfc);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(0xd3d3d3);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBorder(newBorder3);
    }`

Style for Top MultiButton in a list (top rounded)

    `public void setMultiButtonStyleRoundTopOnly(MultiButton mb)
    {
        //mb.setUIID("MultiButtonTop");
        RoundRectBorder newBorder = RoundRectBorder.create().cornerRadius(4).bottomOnlyMode(true);
        newBorder.stroke(1, false);
        newBorder.strokeColor(0xd6d6d6);
        newBorder.strokeOpacity(255);
        newBorder.shadowSpread(10);
        newBorder.shadowX(0.5f);
        newBorder.shadowY(0.5f);
        newBorder.shadowBlur(10);
        RoundRectBorder newBorder2 = RoundRectBorder.create().cornerRadius(4).bottomOnlyMode(true); //need a border object for each style otherwise it breaks
        newBorder2.stroke(1, false);
        newBorder2.strokeColor(0xd6d6d6);
        newBorder2.strokeOpacity(255);
        newBorder2.shadowSpread(10);
        newBorder2.shadowX(0.5f);
        newBorder2.shadowY(0.5f);
        newBorder2.shadowBlur(10);
        RoundRectBorder newBorder3 = RoundRectBorder.create().cornerRadius(4).bottomOnlyMode(true); //need a border object for each style otherwise it breaks
        newBorder3.stroke(1, false);
        newBorder3.strokeColor(0xd6d6d6);
        newBorder3.strokeOpacity(255);
        newBorder3.shadowSpread(10);
        newBorder3.shadowX(0.5f);
        newBorder3.shadowY(0.5f);
        newBorder3.shadowBlur(10);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xfcfcfc);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(newBorder);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBorder(newBorder2);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBgColor(0xfcfcfc);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(0xd3d3d3);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBorder(newBorder3);
    }`

Style for center MultiButton in a list (square)

    `public void setMultiButtonStyle(MultiButton mb)
    {
        Border lineBorder = Border.createLineBorder(1,0xd6d6d6);
        Border emptyBorder = Border.createEmpty();
        Border newBorder = Border.createCompoundBorder(lineBorder, emptyBorder, lineBorder, lineBorder);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xfcfcfc);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(newBorder);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBorder(newBorder);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBgColor(0xfcfcfc);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(0xd3d3d3);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBorder(newBorder);
    }`

Style for bottom button in a list (bottom rounded)

    `public void setMultiButtonStyleRoundBottomOnly(MultiButton mb)
    {
        RoundRectBorder newBorder = RoundRectBorder.create().cornerRadius(4).topOnlyMode(true);
        newBorder.stroke(1, false);
        newBorder.strokeColor(0xd6d6d6);
        newBorder.strokeOpacity(255);
        newBorder.shadowSpread(10);
        newBorder.shadowX(0.5f);
        newBorder.shadowY(0.5f);
        newBorder.shadowBlur(10);
        RoundRectBorder newBorder2 = RoundRectBorder.create().cornerRadius(4).topOnlyMode(true); //need a border object for each style otherwise it breaks
        newBorder2.stroke(1, false);
        newBorder2.strokeColor(0xd6d6d6);
        newBorder2.strokeOpacity(255);
        newBorder2.shadowSpread(10);
        newBorder2.shadowX(0.5f);
        newBorder2.shadowY(0.5f);
        newBorder2.shadowBlur(10);
        RoundRectBorder newBorder3 = RoundRectBorder.create().cornerRadius(4).topOnlyMode(true); //need a border object for each style otherwise it breaks
        newBorder3.stroke(1, false);
        newBorder3.strokeColor(0xd6d6d6);
        newBorder3.strokeOpacity(255);
        newBorder3.shadowSpread(10);
        newBorder3.shadowX(0.5f);
        newBorder3.shadowY(0.5f);
        newBorder3.shadowBlur(10);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xfcfcfc);
        mb.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(newBorder);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBorder(newBorder2);
        mb.getDisabledStyle().setBgColor(0xfcfcfc);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(0xd3d3d3);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        mb.getPressedStyle().setBorder(newBorder3);
    }`

I still haven't tested this on a device, only in the simulator

End result:

[image]

Comment: If you would have used the designer or CSS you could have styled GroupElementFirst/Last & GroupElement. This would have applied to everything. Also styling `MultiButton` border to empty should have worked. I noticed you only styled unselected style and not all styles which might have had an impact.

Comment: Very interesting. I will testbthe second part later today. FYI ComponentGroupFirst isn't allowed to not derive its border in the designer. Might be a bug

Comment: How is it blocked in the designer? I don't follow?

Comment: Sry I probably was being too vague. If you try to edit the RoundCorner Border's radii of ComponentGroupFirst in the designer, the end result is that the border disappears alltogether instead of getting its new, derived style

Comment: I also tried your other suggestion `mb.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());` but this didn't remove the underline

Comment: Odd, I'll need to experiment with this a bit to see what's going on there. I've been working mostly with CSS recently and didn't touch the designer in a while.